# Menu onclick show and hide a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a menu with three items: menu1, menu2, menu3.

I would like to be able to click each button inside the menu and show the related container `div`.

This works already.

I can't seem to make the related `div` hide when the button is clicked again.

My code:

```js
function textshowhide(text, head) {
  var menu_txt = "menu_txt";
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (menu_txt + i != text) {
      if (document.getElementById(menu_txt + i))
        document.getElementById(menu_txt + i).className = "container_hide";
    } else {
      if (document.getElementById(text))
        document.getElementById(text).className = "container_show";

    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container_hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container_show {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu1" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt1','menu1')">Menu 1</li>
  <li id="menu2" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt2','menu2')">Menu 2</li>
  <li id="menu3" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt3','menu3')">Menu 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="menu_txt1" class="container_hide">Page1</div>
<div id="menu_txt2" class="container_hide">Page2</div>
<div id="menu_txt3" class="container_hide">Page3</div>
```

Comment: so what exactly do u want to achieve here? Do you need to reset to initial state on selected menu is clicked again?

Comment: yes. @orangespark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are writing a lot of code. :)

```js
function textshowhide(text) {
  var menu_txt = "menu_txt";
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if(text==i){
    document.getElementById(menu_txt+i).classList.toggle("container_show");
    }else{
    document.getElementById(menu_txt+i).className="container_hide";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container_hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container_show {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu1" onclick="textshowhide('1')">Menu 1</li>
  <li id="menu2" onclick="textshowhide('2')">Menu 2</li>
  <li id="menu3" onclick="textshowhide('3')">Menu 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="menu_txt1" class="container_hide">Page1</div>
<div id="menu_txt2" class="container_hide">Page2</div>
<div id="menu_txt3" class="container_hide">Page3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will take care of it. You can just check if the `show` class is present change it.

```js
function textshowhide(text, head) {
  var menu_txt = "menu_txt";
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (menu_txt + i != text) {
      if (document.getElementById(menu_txt + i))
        document.getElementById(menu_txt + i).className = "container_hide";
    } else {
      if (document.getElementById(text)){
        if(document.getElementById(text).classList.contains('container_show'))
          document.getElementById(text).className = "container_hide";
        else
          document.getElementById(text).className = "container_show";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container_hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container_show {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu1" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt1','menu1')">Menu 1</li>
  <li id="menu2" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt2','menu2')">Menu 2</li>
  <li id="menu3" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt3','menu3')">Menu 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="menu_txt1" class="container_hide">Page1</div>
<div id="menu_txt2" class="container_hide">Page2</div>
<div id="menu_txt3" class="container_hide">Page3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the current class on clicked element. If the menu is opened, just close that. Else open it.

The important code is *when current classname is 'container_show' set 'container_hide'*.

```
document.getElementById(text).className = document.getElementById(text).className == "container_show" ? "container_hide" : "container_show";
```

```js
function textshowhide(text, head) {
  var menu_txt = "menu_txt";
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
if (menu_txt + i != text) {
  if (document.getElementById(menu_txt + i))
    document.getElementById(menu_txt + i).className = "container_hide";
} else {
  if (document.getElementById(text))
    document.getElementById(text).className = document.getElementById(text).className == "container_show" ? "container_hide" : "container_show";

}
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container_hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container_show {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu1" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt1','menu1')">Menu 1</li>
  <li id="menu2" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt2','menu2')">Menu 2</li>
  <li id="menu3" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt3','menu3')">Menu 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="menu_txt1" class="container_hide">Page1</div>
<div id="menu_txt2" class="container_hide">Page2</div>
<div id="menu_txt3" class="container_hide">Page3</div>
```

Comment: oops I was 7 mins late...:P

Answer (score 0):

Do like this way:

```js
function textshowhide(text, head) {
  var menu_txt = "menu_txt";
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (menu_txt + i != text) {
      if (document.getElementById(menu_txt + i))
        document.getElementById(menu_txt + i).className = "container_hide";
    } else {
      if (document.getElementById(text))
        if(document.getElementById(text).className=="container_show"){
           document.getElementById(text).className = "container_hide";
        }else{
          document.getElementById(text).className = "container_show";
        }

    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container_hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container_show {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="menu1" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt1','menu1')">Menu 1</li>
  <li id="menu2" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt2','menu2')">Menu 2</li>
  <li id="menu3" onclick="textshowhide('menu_txt3','menu3')">Menu 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="menu_txt1" class="container_hide">Page1</div>
<div id="menu_txt2" class="container_hide">Page2</div>
<div id="menu_txt3" class="container_hide">Page3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function textshowhide(text , head) {
   $("div").hide();
   var menu_txt = "menu_txt";
   for(let i = 1;i < 4;i++ ){
       if("menu_txt"+i != text){
          $("#menu_txt"+i).removeClass("container_show")
          $("#menu_txt"+i).addClass("container_hide") ;
      }else{
          $(text).removeClass("container_hide")
          $(text).addClass("container_show") ;
       }
   }
```